# Simplest way to get fully qualified name of a module

Tags: python, python-import, fully-qualified-naming

How can one get the fully qualified name of a *module* in Python, at the module level?

For example, let's say this is the file structure:

```
foo
├── setup.py
└── bar
    └── baz
        └── spam.py
```

From within the `spam.py` file at the module level, how can I get the fully qualified module name `"bar.baz.spam"`?

---

There is `__file__`, which one can pair with `inspect.getmodulename(__file__)` to get the module name `"spam"`.  However, how can I turn this into `"bar.baz.spam"`?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from bar.baz import spam

print(spam.__name__)
```

If the name being imported is not a module, you can get the module name and object name like this:

```
from bar.baz.spam import MyClass

print(MyClass.__module__, MyClass.__name__)
```

Comment: I didn't know about that `from bar.baz import spam` could be placed at the module level of `spam`.  That works perfectly, thank you!